# Opendaylight: Message Deserialization failed. How to correlate to flow?

Tags: opendaylight

I have the following exception in my log:

```
 Message deserialization failed
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Deserializer for key: msgVersion: 4    objectClass: org.opendaylight.yang.gen.v1.urn.opendaylight.openflow.protocol.rev130731.ErrorMessage msgType: 65535 experimenterID: 1330529792 was not found - please verify that all needed deserializers ale loaded correctly
```

This is occurring because of some flow that my ODL java application previously wrote into the config data store (which was subsequently written to the switch by the southbound API) but I don't know which the offending flow is. I would like to know how to debug this. How can I correlate this exception to the corresponding flow?

Thanks,

Ranga

Answer (score 0):

This could be known bug https://jira.opendaylight.org/projects/OPNFLWPLUG/issues/OPNFLWPLUG-917 ?

PS, disclaimer: I know very openflowplugin [OFP] internals; just saw this by chance and thought this would be of interest to you.  You could contact https://lists.opendaylight.org/mailman/listinfo/openflowplugin-dev for more.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  It does not seem related to that one. One question I have is how to make sense of the stack trace.

Comment: Write to the https://lists.opendaylight.org/mailman/listinfo/openflowplugin-dev mailing list to get better help about this openflowplugin error.

Answer (score 0):

Error log/stack trace will give you enough information on where exactly you have hit the issue, in case if you are adding a new experimenter deserializer you will have to make sure it is registered into the registry. I see no way to hit this if you have registered your deserializer and you can capture wireshark and compare traces with the packet capture. 
OFDecoder is the start point and you can run through code after that. 
Lastly, which version of OFP are you using? if it is post carbon you must read about singeLayerSerialization.